# In Django Rest Api, how do you return only the Items the owner uploaded

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The Viewset def list looks like this:

```
class ThreeDimensionalModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = ThreeDimensionalModelSerializer
    queryset = ThreeDimensionalModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def list(self, request):
        models = ThreeDimensionalModel.objects.all()
        serializer = ThreeDimensionalModelSerializer(models, many=True)
        print(request.user.id)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The serializer looks like this:

```
class ThreeDimensionalModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ThreeDimensionalModel
        fields = ['File', 'Uploaded', 'Owner', 'Previous', 'SharedWithUser']
        read_only_fields = ['Owner']
```

The model looks like this:

```
class ThreeDimensionalModel(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='models')
    Owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='Owner')
    Uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Previous = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    SharedWithUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='SharedWithUser')
```

When a user requests models at /api/models it should only show the models that are the same owner Id as his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no additional data is sent with that request then obviously you can't filter by user.

The straightforward way to do it is that for logged in users the cookie will contain user information such as userId.

When your endpoint recognizes the user who made the requested is logged in, it will use that as the filter for the query instead of all() as seen in the Django docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

To summarize - if the user is not logged in (or supplies the information as part of the request in some way) then the request is *anonymous* and there is no way to know who made it

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention, that the User needs to be logged in to make the request. The "print(request.user.id)" returns the correct user id who is making the request.

Comment: Then it should be very simple, just follow the documentation i linked to change how the model store is queried - Instead of all() use filter()

Comment: Yes thank you! I made it work with: "models = ThreeDimensionalModel.objects.filter(Owner=request.user.id)"